# Access to UIKit objects in xCode UI testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, xcode-ui-testing

I need to make screenshots during the UI test, but I can't get the UIWindow object, only the XCUIElement. Is there a way to get the real UIKit object?
P.S. I'm using Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to access the underlying `UIKit` objects under UI Testing, as the framework is meant to be used as a [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). The tests essentially have no idea what's "really" going on under the hood; they can only interface via the accessibility API.

As for screenshots, have you looked at Xcode's test output? Click "Show Report Navigator" <kbd>⌘ 8</kbd> to view the screenshots that Xcode automatically takes when a test fails.

These screenshots are from the [WWDC 2015 video on UI Testing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/).

[image: Xcode Report Navigator]
[image: Example Test Failure Screenshot]

You could also trigger manual screenshots by explicitly failing a test at certain times. Make sure to turn off `continuesAfterFailure`.

```
@interface ScreenshotTests : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic) XCUIApplication *app;
@end

@implementation ScreenshotTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    self.continueAfterFailure = YES;
    self.app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [self.app launch];
}

- (void)testManualScreenshot {
    [self.app.textFields[@"username"] typeText:@"joemasilotti"];
    [self recordFailureWithDescription:@"Taking Screenshot" inFile:@"" atLine:0 expected:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: I got, thanks. And as I understand we can't access to the model in our app too? (for example database changes)

Comment: Correct. You will have to validate model changes via their respective UI changes.